lambda Invoked once, code logs twice, when called multiple times
I have a lambda on aws running a dockerized python code. when I run the lambda 2 times back to back, it will double log, but when ran 3 times or more, or only once, it only logs one time.
now, what do I mean by double logging?
START RequestId: <UUID>
{"message": "starting to do something"...}
{"message": "starting to do something"...}
{"message": "another log message with context data in it"...}
{"message": "another log message with context data in it"...}
REPORT RequestId: <UUID>
END RequestId: <UUID>

as you can see, lambda is logging its system logs only once, but my code logs are logged twice.
I also checked monitoring charts for my lambda and it definitely ran once, but the code is double logged.
I do log my code like the following:
def make_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger('my_name')
    ...
    return logger


def handler(event,context):
    logger = make_logger()
    logger.info("starting to do something")
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body']
    # some other code and logic
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, message)
    logger.info("another log message with context data in it") 

I'm suspecting that something fishy is going on there with how I'm making my logger. I don't think it's the loggerAddapter because logs before it is also duplicated.
update1: while adding print statements to my code as suggested in the comments, I could not get the print statement results, but something interesting happened:
I passed in data that would break the lambda code before the adapter was run to see the effect, and the lambda retries, and then I got up to 8 times the logs, in one run for the retries (second retry).

Looks like your logging is behaving strangely. If you replaced logger.info() with print(), does it still double-log?

Side-note: I note that your code is using event['Records'][0]['body'], which means it is only looking at the first record passed to the function. This wouldn't explain your double-logging, but you might want to check whether the invocation might contain multiple records, in which case your code should loop through each record and process it accordingly. Otherwise, it could be skipping-over records to process.

@JohnRotenstein thanks for the side-note. I have the SQS trigger configured to send a batch of 1 message and lambda is configured for a concurrency of 999. so we only get one message, I will look up to see if there is a way to get one message only and so there is no need for magic 0 in there.

You'll always receive a list of records from SQS, so you'll need the [0] or a for record in events['Records']: in there anyway.

the answer was in a small part I left out in the question:
def make_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger('my_name')

    logger.propagate = False
    formatter = UtilFormatter(get_default_log_format())
    log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(log_handler)

    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return logger

when a lambda is called multiple times back to back, it will run in the same lambda instance. so they will be running make_logger function and will be adding a handler to the list of handlers we already have because these handlers won't be cleared as we expect them.
the fix was a simple if statement:
def make_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger('my_name')

    logger.propagate = False
    if not logger.handlers:
        formatter = UtilFormatter(get_default_log_format())
        log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(log_handler)

        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return logger

